# jQuery / Javascript - Dynamically insert text into URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

I have written some PHP that detects whether a user is visiting my blog posts using a mobile device or a computer.

Basically, I need a script that edits the URL dynamically if a user is visiting my blog post with a mobile.

For example, my blog post URLs are like this:

> http://www.example.com/blog/blog-post-1/
>   http://www.example.com/blog/welcome-to-my-blog/
>   http://www.example.com/blog/another-blog-post/

Users should be dynamically redirected to:

> http://www.example.com/m/blog/blog-post-1/
>   http://www.example.com/m/blog/welcome-to-my-blog/
>   http://www.example.com/m/blog/another-blog-post/

I also have the device detection working in PHP, so I just need the script to insert inside the PHP condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: this should be tagged as a `php` question, and possibly an `htaccess` question, but not a `javascript` or `jquery` question.

Comment: OK, sorry, I did not know the best method of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($mobile) {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/m".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess snippet might help to accomplish what you're looking to do:

This rewrite covers most mobile devices (with few false positives). When a mobile device is detected it is redirected to /m/.

http://snipplr.com/view/44741/

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using PHP to do device detection, this should do it:

```
header("Location: /m{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
exit;
```

It takes the current path and prefixes it with `"/m"` to form the mobile path.

Using JavaScript to do the redirection would exclude certain mobile devices, so that's probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

$server

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

user_agent.php:

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true)
{
header('Location: http://mobile.site.com/');
//OR
echo "<script>window.location='http://mobile.site.com'</script>";
}
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
include('user_agent.php'); // Redirecting http://mobile.site.info
// site.com data
?>
```

Content from [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/09/redirect-mobile-devices-with-php.html) site.